# Why does Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Advertisement always return "" for LocalName

Tags: windows, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

It seems that Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Advertisement always returns "" for LocalName. Are there addition steps that are required before Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Advertisement will return the local name of an advertising device? Below is the snippet of code that demonstrates the behavior:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        var watcher = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher();

        watcher.ScanningMode = BluetoothLEScanningMode.Active;
        watcher.Received += OnAdvertisementReceived;
        watcher.Start();
    }

    private void OnAdvertisementReceived(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher,           BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        // Tell the user we see an advertisement and print some properties
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Advertisement:"));
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("  BT_ADDR: {0}", eventArgs.BluetoothAddress));
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("  FR_NAME: {0}", eventArgs.Advertisement.LocalName));
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Because advertisement does not include name data.

Comment: The following was copied from

Comment: Can confirm this behaviour (bug?) where another platform can pick up the local name without issue. Not sure whether it's part of the scan response but like OP I have active scanning enabled.